# How to add a view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been researching up on how to add views and I'm stumped. I want to add a view and all I get are 404 errors. All the examples I see on the web are just to add a default controller. I have a default controller, now I want to add a new page passed an ID in the URL.

This is the controller `xyz.php`:

```
class Xyz extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
        $this->load->model('xyz_model');
        $this->load->view('xyz_main_view');
    }

    public function activity() {
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
        $this->load->model('xyz_model');
        $this->load->view('xyz_activity_view');
    }
}
```

Model is `xyz_model.php`, and views are `xyz_main_view.php` and `xyz_activity_view.php`.

This is `routes.php`:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'xyz'; // works okay
// $route['xyz'] = 'xyz/activity';  // 404
// $route['activity'] = 'xyz/activity'; // 404
// $route['xyz/activity'] = 'xyz/activity'; // 404
// ... many, many other different approaches
```

I'm able to use `http://localhost`, but I'd like to use the following:

```
// map to main view
http://localhost/index
http://localhost/xyz
http://localhost/xyz/index

// map to activity view
http://localhost/activity
http://localhost/xyz/activity
```

My understanding is that some of the URLs for the main view should work automatically, not seeing it. Just `http://localhost`.

I haven't even touched how to get an ID from the URL for the activity page. Just want to get over this first hurdle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep this code in routes

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'xyz';
```

Then Try this URL to execute "activity()" function in xyz controller.

```
http://localhost/[YOUR PROJECT FOLDER NAME]/index.php/xyz/activity
```

To Pass Parameters such as id's you can use this url.

```
http://localhost/[YOUR PROJECT FOLDER NAME]/index.php/xyz/activity/[ID]
```

For more information please check codeigniter routing library. It is really easy to understand. 
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: I see what was missing: modifications to `config.php` and `.htaccess`.

Comment: In `config.php`, removing the index page, e.g. setting to `$config['index_page'] = '';`, and adding an `.htaccess` file under root with lines
`RewriteEngine on␍` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f␍` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d␍` `RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]␍`